# Convert vertical matrix to horizontal

Tags: matlab

How can I convert a vertical matrix to horizontal one?

My code:

```
headersName = get(handles.tagTable, 'ColumnName');

headersName = 

    'Col1'
    'Col2'
    'Col3'
    'Col4'
```

But I need horizontal matrix like this:

```
headersName =

     'Col1'  'Col2'  'Col3'  'Col4'
```

Comment: You;d have to use a cell matrix... what's your end goal? Why do you need it in this form?

Comment: @RobertP. why not just transposing it? `headersName'`? What's "tricky" in this case?

Comment: ...`transpose(...)` not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the way `headersName` is printed by MATLAB it seems like a cell array of strings so a simple transpose should work

```
headersName = get(handles.tagTable, 'ColumnName').';
```

otherwise, if it is a string array you can use `cellstr` to convert it to a cell array and then apply tranpose:

```
headersName = cellstr(get(handles.tagTable, 'ColumnName')).';
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to work with cell array in this case:

> > headersName={'Col1';'Col2';'Col3';'Col4'}

headersName =

```
'Col1'
'Col2'
'Col3'
'Col4'
```

> > headersName'

ans =

```
'Col1'    'Col2'    'Col3'    'Col4'
```